# Error while executing binary file

Tags: c#, process, mono

Ok, hello there. I have some code which should execute my binary file and print all output:

```
Process Program = new Process();
Program.StartInfo.FileName = "file.bin";
Program.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/Build." + this.name;
Program.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Program.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Program.Start();
string output = Program.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Program.WaitForExit(1000);
Console.Out.WriteLine(output);
```

But when i ran it i get this error:

[image]

At the screenshot you can see file name and full path. Ok, we go in console:

[image]

Hey! But that file exists! I already tried that with relative path. Still not working.

P.S. Mono, Ubuntu 14.04
P.P.S. When i remove `UseShellExecute = false` my file is opening in `gedit`.
P.P.P.S. File is 100% exists:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine("Build." + this.name, "file.bin"));
Console.Out.WriteLine(fi.Exists); //true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation for [`ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx)

"When `UseShellExecute` is `false`, the `WorkingDirectory` property is not used to find the executable. Instead, it is used only by the process that is started and has meaning only within the context of the new process. When `UseShellExecute` is `false`, **the `FileName` property must be a fully qualified path to the executable.**"

Comment: @Efog "P.P.S. When i remove UseShellExecute = false my file is opening in gedit." was the clue :)